# Autoformatting AS3 Code

Tags: actionscript-3

Since Adobe, in their infinite wisdom, decided to ditch autoformat from Adobe Flash CC, is there a 3rd party tool that can do this? It just saves so much time and makes life a LOT easier.

Comment: Tools like FDT or IntelliJ IDEA provide extensive formatters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adobe Flash CC has autoformat tool. Try to update Flash CC. Adobe returned autoformat tool since 13.1 version.

[image]